# Post/Get Request not sending parameters

Tags: php, post, curl, request

I am trying to send username and password through post request to login page on my localhost. 
I am using below code to generate request and send it to the page

```
$url='http://localhost/index.php';
$fields = array('username' => 'admin', 'password' => '1234');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

**Edit**
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); prints this information
Array ( [url] => http://www.url.com/index.php [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 380 [request_size] => 182 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 2.234 [namelookup_time] => 0.063 [connect_time] => 0.063 [pretransfer_time] => 0.063 [size_upload] => 28 [size_download] => 2322 [speed_download] => 1039 [speed_upload] => 12 [download_content_length] => 2322 [upload_content_length] => 28 [starttransfer_time] => 2.234 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => ::1 [primary_port] => 80 [local_ip] => ::1 [local_port] => 54953 [redirect_url] => ) Array ( [Host] => localhost [Accept] => */* [Content-Length] => 28 [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded )

The request is generated and I receive HTTP 200, OK status as response. The request is not sending any parameters with it, and in response I receive normal login form instead of after login screen.

Anyone please tell me what is wrong with above code.

I have tried same with stream_context_create and file_get_contents but same reponse is generated in both cases(login form instead of post login screen) like they are receving any parameters.

Comment: Put bool to the CURLOPT_POST option

Comment: Add this line: `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` before `curl_close`

Comment: @Phantom, Its producing same result.

Comment: @hindmost, Tried to look information through this option, but it doesn't provide any useful. If you like I can paste the produced result.

Comment: It is in your interest to provide any detail, if you want to get help

Answer (score 0):

1) `CURLOPT_POST` option expect value of `boolean` type. However it doesn't matter in your code since `count($fields)` will be casted to `true` if `$fields` is non-empty.

2) Don't build `POST` data manually, use [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead. Also you can pass `array` of data to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option and will convert it to `string` automatically .

3) You don't need to set `Content-Type` header since cURL will set it automatically for POST request.

Comment: @user3778430 You have to update code in the question according to changes you've done